# Matching a list of words with a sentence

Tags: php

I have a list of "bad" words having around 450 words in it.

I'm trying to check the sentence for it with

```
<?php
$sentence = "A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
foreach($words as $word) {
    $check  =   strstr($sentence,$word);
    if(!empty($check))
        return false;        
}
return true;
?>
```

Is there a faster and better approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a `preg_split` and `array_intersect`

```
<?php
$sentence = "A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$sntce_wrds = preg_split('/\s+/', $sentence);
return count(array_intersect($sntnce_words, $words)) > 0;
```

Comment: The `preg_split` approach has the advantage of working even if you have tabs or multiple spaces in a row.

Answer (score 0):

I think [preg_replace](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) should fit your needs as well. Pass the $words array as the pattern and space as the replacement. Then match the result with the original string. For e.g

```
$newStr = preg_replace($words, '', $sentence);

if($newStr !== $sentence)
    return false;

return true;
```

Let know if this helps.

Edit: As pointed out by stillstanding, the words in the $words array need to be valid regexes. So this method would only work if the words are changed to patterns like "one" to "/one/".

Edit-2 : If you want to for some reason preserve the words array, then use

```
$wordArr = preg_replace("/(.*)/", '/\1', $words);
```

to convert all words to valid regexes. I think even with this overhead, it should be faster than strstr on a long list.

Comment: Also, note that strstr is slower than strpos http://net-beta.net/ubench/index.php?t=strpos1. Not sure how the regex speed would fare but since it is one shot i would think it is faster.

Comment: Each element in the `$words` array has to be a valid regex. Splitting alone will not work if `$words` is sent to `preg_replace`.